# Insert multiple Dataframes into postgres table in a function using scala

Tags: postgresql, scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a function :

```
 def PopulatePostgres(df: DataFrame ,df1: DataFrame,df2: DataFrame   table: String): Result = {
    val result = Try({

      df
        .write
        .format("jdbc")
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .option("url", config.url)
        .option("user", config.username)
        .option("password", config.password)
        .option("dbtable", table)
        .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
        .save()
    })

    result match {
      case Success(_) => Result(s"Created ${table}")
      case Failure(problem) => {
        log.error(problem.getMessage)
        Result(s"Failed to create ${table}")
      }
    }
  }
```

But,I am not sure how to dump the 3 dataframes one by one into the postgres table .So I need to insert df,df1,df2 all into the postgres table .Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store all the data frames into the same table.

```
val findaldf = df.union(df1).union(df2)
```

Then you can use your persitance logic.

But all df's are want to store separately

```
List(df, df1, df2).map(_.write.format("jdbc")
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .option("url", config.url)
        .option("user", config.username)
        .option("password", config.password)
        .option("dbtable", table)
        .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
        .save())
```

Comment: Actually I need to avoid Union operation

Answer (score 0):

If the schema of all the Dataframes are same (and of course you want them in one table) then you can combine all the them in one and then push the data to postgres else loop it for each dataframe and push the data.

```
val result = df.unionAll(df1).unionAll(df2)
```

Comment: Actually I need to avoid Union operation

Comment: Then you can loop through the dataframes and push data to postgres as @Ravi suggested.

Comment: sorry.But i am not understanding how can I loop through the dataframes.Can you please help me